# Why SQL Fiddle doesn't work during "Building schema" and "Run SQL" functions?

Tags: mysql, build, schema, fiddle

I'm practicing learning MySQL code with SQL Fiddle, it worked sometimes but now I get errors all the time when I use the "Build schema" or "Run SQL" functions.
After a while, the error printed is "Unable to get host connection: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!"

Anyone know how to solve the problem? Is there another tool I can use to do practice with queries to my schema?

Comment: Are you talking about the web site http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: While this is no particular training tool and does not give you an already filled database for testing, you could use XAMPP or LAMP to locally host a database server and then for instance use the Webserver to include and use a tool like phpmyadmin.

Comment: Best install mysql locally - I have experienced some odd behaviours in sqlfiddle and alternatives eg db-fiddle, and the fiddles won't necssarily exactly match your production environment (version) anyway.

Comment: The various database fiddles are all labors of love by their creators. Having a beefy enough infrastructure to handle all sorts of different dbms server makes and versions is expensive, and the operators of those fiddles pay for it themselves.. You could consider donating.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, Sorry if I didn't specify it

Answer (score 0):

Install your [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/binary-packages/) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/) database server on your local machine. Install a decent native SQL client program. [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) is great on Windows. There are plenty for Mac.  Any modern laptop computer (since about 2014) can handle a student- or developer- scale database server and client without breaking a sweat.

You can install [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). But that's a php web app, so you also have to install a web server and php to get it working. Hence the suggestions for XAMPP or LAMP stack packages. I prefer the native clients; less to go wrong; less stuff in your laptop.

It's best to reserve the database fiddles for sharing SQL demos with other people. Like for Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've already installed MAMP to practice with PHP, and there I saw phpmyadmin that I used fo some wordpress project in local. I tried to create a new database and it work perfectly for my didactics purposes, I can wrote code and do query.